# Is cooling by infrared absorbing rectenna possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, infrared-radiation

We know that every hot objects emits IR radiation.
We also know that plasmonic rectenna can absorb and convert IR radiation to electricity.
Question: what will happen if we put an hot object inside a cube that has absorbing rectenna on its walls? Will the object inside getting cooled to zero kelvin by radiation IR and receiving no reflections?

Imagine the perfect situation in which there is no other heat transfer like convection and cube's wall are perfect absorbers.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can not cool the cavity down to absolute zero. An antenna that can convert electromagnetic radiation to electricity can also convert electricity to electromagnetic radiation. As the temperature of the rectenna increases, it will emit more and more electromagnetic radiation, until it is at thermal equilibrium with the cavity.

Having a rectenna isn't really substantially different from just having one of the walls of the cavity be cooler than the others- either way it will cool down the cavity while heating itself, until eventually they reach thermal equilibrium.